# Quadratic Equation; Roots' Magnitude Less than 1

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, roots, quadratics

What are the conditions on $a$ and $b$ so that the roots (real or complex) of the equation have magnitude $< 1$.

$$λ^2 − (a − b + 1)λ + a = 0$$

On a separate note, if you could explain (NOT Required for answer though):

Standard results from dynamic
system theory say that the time behavior of the particle depends on the eigenvalues of the dynamic matrix
$A$. The eigenvalues $λ_1$ and $λ_2$ (either real or complex)
are the solutions of the equation:
$$λ_2 − (a − b + 1)λ + a = 0$$
The necessary and sufficient condition for the equilibrium point given by Eq. (17) to be stable (an attractor) is that both eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ (whether
real or complex) have magnitude less than 1.

Comment: What is equation 17?

Comment: @GoodDeeds It is apparently an attractor.

Comment: In the second equation, should it be $\lambda_2$ and should the $\lambda$ then be $\lambda_1$, or should both be just $\lambda$ ?

Comment: I think the second equation should be the same as the first - i.e. the $\lambda_2$ in the second equation should really be $\lambda^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the roots of this equation:$$\lambda^2-(a-b+1)\lambda+a=0$$then we have:$$\lambda_1+\lambda_2=a-b+1\tag{1}$$$$\lambda_1\lambda_2=a\tag{2}$$We are also told that:$$|\lambda_1|\lt1$$$$|\lambda_2|\lt1$$$$\therefore |\lambda_1+\lambda_2|\lt2$$These condition applied to (2) yield:$$|a|\lt1$$and applied to (1) yield:$$|a-b+1|\lt2$$